How to upload a file and show it in a dialog window
I am using React with Ant Design as component library. I want to implement the following behavior:
The user clicks a button and the Explorer window opens to upload a file. When the user clicks to select a file, a popup window appears showing the file.
My problem is that the uploaded file is displayed next to the button. I don't know how to prevent it from appearing there and instead show it in the popup window.
I struggle to understand how to structure my components and how they should interact.
For example my component UploadFile: How do I trigger the upload window without being the button the respective upload area?
function UploadFile() {
  const onUpload = () => {
    console.log('asdf')
  }

  return (
    <Upload name="file" accept=".json" customRequest={onUpload}>
      <Button icon={<ImportIcon />} />
    </Upload>
  )
}


I finally found the answer:
There is a field called showUploadList and you can set it to false, so it does not display the uploaded file.
function UploadFile() {
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState<string | null>()
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)

  const onSelectFile = (file) => {
    setFileName(file.name)
    setIsModalVisible(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Upload name="file" accept=".json" showUploadList={false} beforeUpload={onSelectFile}>
        <Button icon={<ImportIcon />} />
      </Upload>
      <Modal title="asdf" visible={isModalVisible} handleOk={undefined} handleCancel={undefined}>
        <p>{fileName ? `you selected ${fileName}` : 'no file selected'}</p>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}

